# ModelForm and custom field

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using Model Form which have custom CharField added.My question is, what is actually the standard way to access custom fields after POST request? This is the way I doing it now:

```
#inside ModelForm 
date = CharField(label='date', widget=Select(choices=[
        ('', '---------'),
        ('N', 'Never')
    ]))

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   self.date = args[0]['date'] #custom date CharField
   return super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
# processing self.date...
```

Is there a better way to do that? Also, date field is using choices as a source of input data.My guess is that choices are the right thing in this particular instance, building a table and model and then using queryset to retrieve a few values wouldn't help much, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    date = self.fields['date']
```

If the values for the choices need to be editable, I would put them in a separate model and use a ModelChoiceField. Otherwise, you're fine just using static choices.

Comment: Thanks! But there's another problem now that I didn't anticipate.Form will be empty when first time it is created, and there's no self.fields then, so this code fails(my code also fails, I used Back button when I tried it, but on new page request it fails). Shoud I test if it is  POST request, and how I can do that inside __init__ ?

Comment: Sounds like I need to take a look at your view and your model.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured that I can access the field with self.cleaned_data['date'] inside overriden form's save() method, and it works.